# Difference between preview and running program

Tags: wpf

Sorry for my bad headline but I couldn't figure out a better one. Heck, I don't even know how to properly ask my question. But here it comes.

I have a custom control in WPF, let's call it  `Cell`. This control does have a few dependency properties, one `Text` to show in the `Cell` and a few "decorative" properties for background color, foreground color and so on. If I use this `Cell` control stand-alone, everything works fine so far.

Then I have another custom control inheriting from `ItemsControl`, let's call it `Field`. This control should show a text and some `Cell`s. it has some "decorative" properties for the text part as well. The information about showing `Cell`s is given to the control by a `DataTemplate`, something like

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate"
              DataType="...">
    <ns:Cell Text="{Binding Text}"
             Background="{Binding ...}" />
</DataTemplate>

...

<ns:Field ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}" />
```

If I use this `Field` control stand-alone, everything works fine so far.

Now I want to show several `Field` controls at once. So I put an `ItemsControl` on my window and gave an `ItemTemplate` again, something like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate"
              DataType="...">
    <ns:Cell Text="{Binding Text}"
             Background="{Binding ...}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="FieldTemplate"
              DataType="...">
    <ns:Field ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}"
              FieldText="{Binding Text}"
              TextBackground="{Binding ...}" />
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FieldTemplate}" />
```

As long as I preview my WPF window everything works fine so far. Changing the values of some "decorative" properties at `Cell` level or at `Field` level is immediately shown in the preview.

But if I run my program it seems that all "decorative" properties at `Cell` level are ignored. I can see all my `Field`s with their respective texts and I can see every `Cell` in every `Field` with their respective texts. But all `Cell`s are plain white. All set colors are not shown.

Snoop tells me, that every color is set to `Transparent` by the `ParentTemplate`.

Visual Studio doesn't show me any exceptions or any binding errors. So I'm kind of stuck at where or how I can find the error and fix it.

So I wanted to ask you, if you may have a hint for me.

Does this contruction with a `DataTemplate` containing a `DataTemplate` and both `DataTemplate`s bind to it's `DataContext` work?

Or does it have something to do with maybe re-using `Brush` objects that shouldn't be re-used?

But why is it working in the preview?

Comment: Could the decorative properties on the Cells not be set, or even missing, in the runtime data, but be there only in your design time data? The DataType property on the DataTemplate is ignored if the x:Key is set.

Comment: Some of the "decorative" properties are bound to properties in the view model, because their value depends on other values from the view model. If I debug my program and look at these properties in the view model they are set properly. And since I don't get any binding errors from Visual Studio either, and since it is working in the preview I assume that all the bindings are ok as well. I think I have to create a small test program to recreate my problem on a smaller level.

Comment: Another gotcha is if you are raising PropertyChanged when your computed properties change? If not the behavior depends on initialization order, which could explain the difference between preview and runtime.